# field with name "date" does not work in pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am working with FastAPI, creating a pydantic model with "date" as the name of one of the field. I notice this will give error, the type being shown on the generated schema would be null. I found a workaround for this, but I wonder why I can't just use this "date" name in the first place.

```
from datetime import date
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Item(BaseModel):
    # d: date = None # works fine
    # date: date = None # does not work
    d: date = Field(..., alias="date") # the workaround

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item
```

Comment: almost every language has his reserved words, which shouldn't be used

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're importing `date` from `datetime`.

So when you use `date` in your code, it is actually the `date` class of `datetime` module. So you can't simply use it as a variable name.

I suggest you to import date as something else

eg: `from datetime import date as date_type`

Comment: wow this has been haunting me for hours, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `None` type is not a `date` object.

If you want to have a nullable date you can do this with `Optional`.

```
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Item(BaseModel):
    your_variable_name: Optional[date] = None
```